# How can I simulate multiple layers of atoms forming Turing patterns?

Tags: atoms, molecular-dynamics

This experiment blew my mind -- they created a Turing pattern in a single atomic layer of bismuth adsorbed on crystalline niobium selenide. https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/tiniest-turing-patterns-found-in-atomically-thin-bismuth/4013979.article

I want to repeat their simulation, and also try different metals. Difficulty: I'm an engineer way out of my depth.

Is there a software package, or python library, that I can do this in? Preferably one that doesn't require a huge learning curve and/or PhD to understand what the tutorial is doing (LAMMPS hurt me). A working example file would be super helpful, of course.